# Get the name of the Command Button I just clicked

Tags: excel, vba, click, caption, commandbutton

I'm new to VBA and stuck with my project.

I have several Command Buttons on my worksheet and they all refer to an ID that should be used later on for calculations. I named the buttons Button_ID1, Button_ID2, ...

The idea is that I extract the name of a particular commend button after clicking and use the ID number as a variable later on.
I've seen many solutions already but most if them are for UserForm and I have my command buttons simple inserted to the sheet.
It's a really simple code but since the number of buttons change according to the code I would need to manually type it to every Click event.

Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub Button_ID1_Click()
    selID = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it activeX or a form control on the sheet?

Comment: Using a "control array" is the typical suggestion for this pattern - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33087989/vba-command-button-array